# Erro no modo offline

Tags: gradle

Estou recebendo este erro todas as vezes que tento abrir um arquivo:

> Error:Could not determine artifacts for com.android.support:design:24.1.1: No cached version available for offline mode

Já habilitei e desabilitei o **offline work**, dentro do Gradle, em Settings, porém, sem sucesso.
Alguém poderia me dar uma luz? Preferivelmente com um caminho, ou mesmo um print, pois como disse, sou iniciante.

Comment: O que você fez é o mesmo desta [resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144598/no-cached-version-of-gradle)?

Comment: Ola Ismael! Sim, é similar, no entanto, nao acho onde fazer o download da nova versao. Inclusive ja desinstalei todo o Andorid Studio, inclusive desinstalei manualmente a pasta de origen do Gradle e todo o SDK, e reinstalei tudo novamente, sem sucesso.

Answer (score 0):

Usando o Android studio:

File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle

Desmarque a opção Offline work e sicronize novamente.

Espero ter ajudado